# Single result of Virt-Top

Tags: bash, ssh, virtual-machine, kvm, libvirt

Is it possible to get one single result of the current stats from virt-top?
I´ve tried to use the `--stream` parameter but with that I get a new result every second.
I only need one result every execute of the command.
How can I reach that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the virt-top man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/virt-top):

> -b
>   Batch mode. In this mode keypresses are ignored.
>
> -n iterations
>   Set the number of iterations to run. The default is to run continuously.

So I think what you want is:

```
virt-top -b -n 1
```

This is exactly the same as how you would achieve the same with [normal "top"](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top).

Comment: Yeah looks nice, but the problem is, that every value in the secion is 0.

Comment: Perhaps `virt-top` needs a couple of iterations before it starts reporting reasonable numbers.  Can you try `-n 2` instead, and just capture the output of the last iteration?